# How to use pickled pretrained weights in Tensorflow 2?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to load a pkl file that was generated in a model trained with tensorflow 1.x in tf2.
`model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)` does not seem to work.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try loading the pickle file then get the weights.

```py
import pickle
import tensorflow as tf

model = pickle.loads('<path>')
loaded_model = model.get_weights()
```